# How do I use Jenkins CI with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation

I'm now at the level where I am able to build my own test automation framework using TestNG, through Selenium. The next stage is for me to look at kicking off automation runs, periodically using Selenium Grid.

I've being doing some research on this, and the CI tool, Jenkins, keeps cropping up. However, there isn't anything out there (that I can find!) that will answer the questions I have on it. Any help would be much appreciated on the following:

1) Why is Jenkins used with Selenium...what does it bring to the party?

2) Can Jenkins be used in conjunction with Selenium Grid? If so, I'm just after some guidance as to how they inter-link?

Andy

Comment: Too broad for SO but Jenkins is just a tool that runs other tools, scripts, etc, that all combine into "your build process". The build process would be getting your code, compiling, maybe deploying it to a test server, then running Selenium and grabbing the results of that test. Selenium Grid is nothing to do with Jenkins, so yes, is the short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment to your question. (new member, and I can't yet comment, so simply restating the comment as a formal answer).

1. As mentioned in the comment, Jenkins is simply a CI tool. As to what it brings to the party: It has some nice features and plugins. So it depends on what you want. You should just check out: http://jenkins-ci.org/
2. Yes. Jenkins provides several different ways to invoke. It has the ability to string build invocations together so you can even build, deploy, then start selenium grid.

Comment: That' great, many thanks for that pilotg. I understand the topic is broad, but this helps with my understanding so I can now dig a bit further. Thanks again